# validate input based on checkbox

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I have an input and a checkbox. You can write in the input and submit which will submit correct data. You can disable the input by clicking on the checkbox and it will submit null value which is what I want. But when you fill the input and disable the input with the checkbox and submit, it will submit the current value but I want it to submit null since it is disabled. I'm using react hook form with yup.

Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-snow-rtc9b0?file=/src/App.js

I have tried to use `setValue` from react hook form(shown in the sandbox) when you check the checkbox it will set the value to null but when you check the checkbox again, the current value will be removed but I want to have the previous value.

Comment: You can also have a state for input, which can be updated using onChange Handler of input... then if you toggle checkbox ... clear the input state.

Comment: Is there any problem here : `const onSubmitHandler = ({ checkbox, number }) => {
    if (checkbox) {
      let newData = { checkbox, number: null };
      console.log(newData);
    } else {
      console.log(checkbox, number);
    }
    
  };`

Comment: @RKataria Could you please show an example?

Comment: @AbhishekKamal I also have tried it before. But the issue is that I have multiple inputs based on multiple checkboxes. So this will not be clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a easy. I just added `|| value` to the `.trasnform` method from yup and it just works!

Here is the working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-pasteur-jnkhpm

Explanation: If you take a look at line `12` we use `.when` for `number` input to conditionally depend on checkbox. When the checkbox is true, then it accepts null values because of `.nullable()` and with `.transform((value) => (Number.isNaN(value) ? null : value))` it only checks if the value is NaN, if so then make it null else return the number. But now we need to change it to `.transform((value) => (Number.isNaN(value) || value ? null : value))` so this means at first place when the checkbox is true(input disabled) and there is value in that input, then return null else return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional validation in your transform function to verify if the current value of your checkbox is true. Updated code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-surf-gxli9r?file=/src/App.js)

```
.transform((value) => Number.isNaN(value) ? null : !isChecked ? value : null )
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the yup validation is in another file and there are multiple inputs and checkboxes?